# Why does MemoryStream.GetBuffer and MemoryStream.Close not exist in NetCoreApp 2?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I want to convert my old project to **netcoreapp2.0** but I have three problems

[image]

Why does the following APIs not exist in NetCoreApp 2 ?

1. MemoryStream.GetBuffer()
2. MemoryStream.Close()
3. BinaryWriter.Close()

While these functions seem to have been implemented

[netstandard2.0_diff](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/standard/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_diff.md)

[.NET Core API Reference version 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0)

How can I access those?

Comment: You don't need to call Close as streams and readers are automatically closed when they are disposed, i.e. at the closing bracket of the using statement. I don't use netcoreapp, but the preferred way to get the MemoryStream content in the .NET framework is by calling ToArray and I suppose that should be existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I used VS 2017 15.2 for creating the project then I build it with dotnet core 2 so **I must delete obj and bin folder** for that and build again, seems some dependencies setting set in obj folder.

Answer (score 3):

`GetBuffer()` was removed. Instead of `GetBuffer()` method you should use `TryGetBuffer()`. If you are interested why ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1897)):

> the reason `GetBuffer` is removed is because it is broken in the general case and would only work for folks that actually constructed the MemoryBuffer themselves and know the exact part of the underlying buffer that is being used. For example, there are constructors on MemoryBuffer that take the buffer and a start index and that start index is not at all reflected in what is returned from GetBuffer so other people that call that without knowing the start index will potentially be looking at memory outside the MemoryStream. That is why TryGetBuffer uses an ArraySegment so it can communicate the start index and the length to the callers so they can properly scope to the underlying buffer being used by MemoryStream.

---

`Close()` method was removed as a duplication of `Dispose`. From original [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10626):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
// ...
} // automatically Disposed(Closed) here
```

or directly call

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
// ...
ms.Dispose() // Closed here
```

**Update**:  looks like info about `Close` only valid for .NET Core < 2.0.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.close?view=netcore-2.0#System_IO_Stream_Close) is `Close()` method description for .NET Core 2.0. Interesting that it is not recommended to use it anyway:

> Instead of calling this method, ensure that the stream is properly disposed. This method calls Dispose, specifying true to release all resources. You do not have to specifically call the Close method. Instead, ensure that every Stream object is properly disposed.

---

Comment: Are you sure ? because I saw those in dotPeek in .net core 2 preview 2 but I dont know why did not work in my VS Code !

Comment: @user7489391 looks like my answer valid only for version < 2.0...

Comment: @user7489391 just to be sure: did you do `dotnet restore` ?

Comment: yes :) I did, of course I use VS Code maybe I have to install VS 2017 15.3 Preview

Comment: @user7489391 it should be enough to only install [.NET Core 2 Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview)

Answer (score 1):

Close method is available in .NET Core 2.0, I've just installed VS 2017 Prev-5.13, which includes .Net Core 2.0 Preview, and I am able to use the Close method.

The new strategy in .NET Core / .NET Standard is to maintain API compatibility as much as possible (not a full compatibility though), so that most of the built binaries are compatible with the new ecosystem.

Some previous decisions to clean up the APIs were reversed to maintain that compatibility where it is not Windows specific.

[image: Screenshot of Stream class]

[image: Screenshot of the VS Version]

Comment: I using VS Code but does not exist !!!

Comment: What version of VS Code

Comment: latest 1.14.2, even I checked in another system but problem exist.